# Xamarin ios requesting unnecessary permissions

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-permissions

I have an Xamarin App for ios and android. Lately Apple has been rejecting my builds due to missing purpose strings, for features my app **does not use.**

My app only needs access to **Camera** and **Media Storage**. I request permission once that feature is being used. However Apple is requiring I explain why my app needs access to:

- contacts
- location
- bluetooth
- siri
- microphone

None of which are in use! It seems like every time I do a release something is added to the list. My info.plist is getting filled with messages like "This app does not require this feature". Its very unprofessional.

It seems that if I use a nuget package that has the *potential* to use a feature, the app thinks that feature IS in use.

Is there a way to make it very clear my app does **NOT** use these features and to **NOT** ask the user for permission to use them when they first run the app? (This is not a programmed permission request that is occurring.)

Comment: Linking usually solves this by stripping away code you are not using.

Comment: My linking is currently set to "Link Framework SDKs only"

Comment: @Shaboboo That will not strip un-used code from 3rd party libraries

Comment: thanks @SushiHangover and Cheesebaron, I will try "Link All" and see if that helps

Comment: My build with "Link All" turned on is crashing on my ipad upon opening. Two crash messages in a row. Could be an unrelated issue however

Comment: Is it because some other referenced library references these permissions ？